# Implement authorization in Laravel using external model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to protect my routes with authorization levels in laravel - client users have access to one group while admin gets access to a separate group. However, the laravel API I'm creating runs concurrent to the existing legacy app which uses its own `Users` class, rather than the pre rolled eloquent Users model that all the docs use.

So far I haven't been able to determine how best to create this custom authorization middleware.

Basically I'd like to do something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'custom_auth', function() {
  Route::get('/' function() {
    return "Hello World"; 
  }
}];

//where 'custom_auth' points to something like

function isAdmin() {
  if (Core\User->check_is_admin()) {
    return true;   
  } else {
    return false; 
  }
}
```

Kind of an open-ended question, I know, so any links to blogs/docs/videos would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are regular users supposed to access the same route as admins? Example: is the route `/api/action/identifier` going to be accessible by admins and regular users or did you want to go down the route of `/api/admin/action/identifier` for admins and `/api/action/identifier` for regular users?

Comment: I use https://packagist.org/packages/ultraware/roles maybe you can implement the same methodology in your middlewares.

Comment: @N.B. there are separate APIs for users and admins, so basically, I need this to reject reqs from non-admin users. I will implement a similar solution for the client API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I added custom middleware to App\Http\Middleware that copied the structure of the prebuilt Middleware\Authenticate.php file and uses the custom `isAdmin()` method.

Make sure to include in HTTP\Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
  'auth_admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateAdmin::class, // <- New Middleware
  ...]
```

Then in my Routes\admin_api

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth_admin'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "Hello World"; 

});
```

This all works!